# Noetherian condition on the ring of formal power series without Axiom of Choice

Tags: commutative-algebra, axiom-of-choice

I use the definition of a Noetherian ring given by Qiaochu in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169550/existence-of-a-prime-ideal-in-an-integral-domain-of-finite-type-over-a-field-wit):
A commutative ring is Noetherian if, for any nonempty collection of ideals $\mathcal{I}$, there is some $I \in \mathcal{I}$ which is not properly contained in any $J \in \mathcal{I}$.

Can we prove the following theorem without using Axiom of Choice?

**Theorem**
Let $A$ be a Noetherian commutative ring.
Let $A[[X]]$ be the ring of formal power series over $A$.
Then $A[[X]]$ is Noetherian.

As for why I think this question is interesting, please see(particularly Pete Clark's answer):
[Why worry about the axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22927/why-worry-about-the-axiom-of-choice/)

Comment: [The same question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154469/can-we-prove-that-the-ring-of-formal-power-series-over-a-noetherian-ring-is-noet) was asked in MathOverflow.